# Signature locked out on GS III running 4.1.2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, exchange, active-sync, signature-error

3/19/2014 This morning, I recreated my MS Exchange account on my phone (GS III running 4.1.2) while troubleshooting e-mails that it didn't detect last night. Now, I learned that I can't change the Signature content; I can only disable this setting. What happened? I'm aware ever since the last time--a few months ago--that I performed this operation, there have been updates to all other apps on my phone, but none directly related to this case. Again, what happened? If this can't be resolved, then I'll just disable the Signature setting.

Approximately 10-11 minutes ago, I triggered a software update check.  It detected one (size is 556.58 MB) and is in download progress.  Why wasn't this update pushed?  Does the carrier, T-Mobile in my case, have a say in this?

Once the SW update is completely installed, I'll post back with an update on the Signature issue.

Comment: You seem to have multiple questions in your post. This site does best when a question post is limited to a single question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, upon completion of the SW update, my phone now has 4.3 (the high end of Jellybean).  And the Signature's functionality has been fully restored; I was able to edit it AND save the changes.  So far, I'm impressed with how the settings were reorganized and the aesthetics of the icons.

Anyway, I'm curious to know how long ago T-Mobile made this update available to GS III owners because I recall on my prior phone with them, I got a notification in the notification bar when there was an update available for Froyo.